# QEMU on Linux works, but on Windows (probably 7/8) fails when -redir parameter is used

Tags: windows, windows-8, qemu, windows-networking

I'm shipping my project via qemu static build and a Linux VM. My project uses port 4848 for server configuration and port 8080 for HTTP (tools) and ephermal ports  (49152+) for spawned sub-projects that use p2p websockets.

Note that the qemu binary is the *qemu-system-...* binary from Linux and the qemu.exe on windows, all statically compiled.

On Linux, I'm starting everything with this command. It works like a charm as expected:

```
./qemu -curses \
-kernel ../vmlinuz \
-initrd ../root.gz \
-L ./ \
-redir tcp:4848::4848 \
-redir tcp:8080::8080 \
-redir tcp:49152::49152 \
-redir tcp:49153::49153 \
-redir tcp:49154::49154 \
-redir tcp:49155::49155 \
-redir tcp:49156::49156 \
-redir tcp:49157::49157 \
-redir tcp:49158::49158 \
-redir tcp:49159::49159 \
-redir tcp:49160::49160 \
-redir tcp:49161::49161 \
-redir tcp:49162::49162 \
-append "quiet autologin loglevel=3"
```

On my Windows XP VM (in VirtualBox), this command here works fine without issues once you have approved the Firewall popup, but it seems to not work on Windows 8:

```
start qemu.exe -kernel ..\vmlinuz -initrd ..\root.gz -L ./ -redir tcp:4848::4848 -redir tcp:8080::8080 -redir tcp:49152::49152 -redir tcp:49153::49153 -redir tcp:49154::49154 -redir tcp:49155::49155 -redir tcp:49156::49156 -redir tcp:49157::49157 -redir tcp:49158::49158 -redir tcp:49159::49159 -redir tcp:49160::49160 -redir tcp:49161::49161 -redir tcp:49162::49162 -append "quiet autologin loglevel=3"
```

I found out that there might be an issue with the NE2000 network card driver on Windows, which I read here: http://www.h7.dion.ne.jp/~qemu-win/HowToNetwork-en.html

When trying to bootup qemu.exe directly without the -redir stuff and the flags "-net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user", it boots up properly.

But when I start to add the -redir flags on Windows8, it crashes and not even shows a single message in the cmd / Terminal.

**Question**

How to properly redir ports of a VM guest to a Windows 8 host with qemu.exe in CMD?